# PathAccessException issue in Android 11 and above

Tags: flutter, dart, storage, android-permissions

I am currently working on developing a file manager type application for Android in Flutter. The primary purpose of this app is to go through the entire file system on the device, retrieving files based on specific extensions. Subsequently, these files will be loaded into the application, allowing users to access lists of files such as videos, etc.

However, I have encountered an obstacle while implementing this functionality on Android 11 and above. I am faced with a PathAccessException, which restricts access to certain directories. Consequently, I am seeking guidance on how to effectively handle this exception. Is there a viable approach to exclude the Android folder exclusively from the listSync(recursive: true) method?

Here is My Method to retrieve Files

```
Future<List<File>?> getFiles() async {
    Directory dir = Directory("/storage/emulated/0");
    int totalSize = 0;
    List<File> files = [];

    if (dir.existsSync()) {
      List<FileSystemEntity> entities = dir.listSync(recursive: true);
      for (FileSystemEntity entity in entities) {
        if (entity is File) {
          File file = entity;
          String extension = file.path.split('.').last.toLowerCase();
          if (extension == 'mp3' || extension == 'mp4'  || extension == 'pdf') {
            int fileSizeInBytes = await file.length();
            totalSize += fileSizeInBytes;
            files.add(file);
          }
        }
      }

      print("Total size : $totalSize bytes");
      return files;
    } else {
      print("directory does not exist.");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And Here How I call This method

```
List<File>? data = await provider.getFiles();
print(data);
```

Here is the Exception

```
E/flutter ( 4188): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter ( 4188): #0      _Directory._fillWithDirectoryListing (dart:io-patch/directory_patch.dart:42:24)
E/flutter ( 4188): #1      _Directory.listSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:233:5)
E/flutter ( 4188): #2      FileManagerProvider.getFiles (package:filesharing/src/screens/file_manager/provider/file_manager_provider.dart:73:45)
E/flutter ( 4188): #3      _BottomTabsScreenState._getFiles (package:filesharing/src/screens/bottom_tabs/screens/bottom_tabs_screen.dart:49:39)
E/flutter ( 4188): #4      _BottomTabsScreenState._init (package:filesharing/src/screens/bottom_tabs/screens/bottom_tabs_screen.dart:30:5)
E/flutter ( 4188): <asynchronous suspension>
```

here is my Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

I also Added this

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android 11 and newer versions, there's a limitation that prevents direct access to certain system folders. Specifically, we can't access the "android" folder. To work around this, we need to exclude the "/storage/emulated/0/Android" part of the file path. Here's how you can achieve this:

When dealing with directories in Android, it's important to consider how your code affects the user interface (UI) responsiveness. If you use dir.listSync(recursive: true), the UI thread might get blocked. This means the user won't be able to interact with the app smoothly while this operation is ongoing. The recursive: true part means that the operation will go through all the folders and their contents within the specified directory.

An alternative approach that doesn't block the UI thread is using await dir.list().toList(). This method won't hinder the UI's responsiveness. Moreover, it will only provide a list of folders within the directory /storage/emulated/0, without delving into the contents of those folders.

Here is the code

```
Future<List<FileSystemEntity>> getFilesFromExternalStorage(int sdk) async {
    Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0');
    List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await dir.list().toList();
    List<FileSystemEntity> finalEntities = [];
    entities.removeWhere((entity) {
      return entity.path == '/storage/emulated/0/Android';
    });
    for(var entity in entities){
      if(entity is Directory){
        try {
          var sub = await entity.list(recursive: true).toList();
          finalEntities.addAll(sub);
        } catch (e) {
          // Handle the error based on your requirements
        }
      }
    }
    return finalEntities;
  }
```

U can also use this package

```
dependencies:
  media_storage: ^0.0.1
```

Here is an example

```
getPathFiles() async {
  List<File> files = [];
  var path = await MediaStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("");
  bool isPermission = await MediaStorage.getRequestStoragePermission();
  if(isPermission){
    List<dynamic>  media = await MediaStorage.getMediaStoreData(path);
    for(var i=0; i<media.length; i++ ){
      FileSystemEntity file = File(media[i]['filepath']);
      if(file is File){
        files.add(file);
      }
    }
  }else{
    await MediaStorage.getRequestStoragePermission();
  }
  return files;
}
```

For more Details Please See This Example https://github.com/Khuntarpit/media_storage/blob/main/example/